# Why do logistic regression standard errors vary depending on which variable is omitted?

Tags: r, regression, logistic, categorical-data

I am trying to estimate the standard errors of the means of a binary outcome variable at different levels of a categorical variable using a logistic regression. However, these standard errors seem to depend on which level of the categorical variable is omitted. This can be reproduced with the following example:

```r
set.seed(5)

var1 = rbinom(100,1,0.3)
var2 = rbinom(100,1,0.6)

conditions_strs = c(rep('var1',100),rep('var2',100))

df1 = data.frame('outcome'=c(var1,var2),
                 'conditions'=conditions_strs)
df1$conditions = as.factor(df1$conditions)

df2 = df1
# Change the omitted category in df2 from var1 to var2
df2$conditions = relevel(df2$conditions,family=binomial,ref='var2')

model1 = glm(outcome ~ conditions,family=binomial,data=df1)
model2 = glm(outcome ~ conditions,family=binomial,data=df2)
```

Calling `summary(model1)` gives:

```
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)     -0.5754     0.2083  -2.762  0.00575 **
conditionsvar2   0.9393     0.2911   3.227  0.00125 **
```

and `summary(model2)`:

```
Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)   
(Intercept)      0.3640     0.2033   1.790  0.07344 . 
conditionsvar1  -0.9393     0.2911  -3.227  0.00125 **
```

If I then want to estimate the standard errors of the estimate of `var1`, which model do I use? Is the standard error estimate for a level that is not omitted dependent on the estimated standard error of the omitted level? Is a logistic regression not the best model to use in this case? I've used a logistic regression here because the problem I'm working on uses a mixed effects logistic regression - however, I discovered the same dynamic exists in logistic regressions without random effects.

Comment: I don't understand your question, because I see *identical* standard errors reported in the two outputs: they are both given as `0.2911`.   Please note that neither model "omits" any level of the variable: they simply encode the values differently.  This will be reflected in a changed intercept: have you noticed that (to the precision reported) the difference of the intercepts is *precisely* the estimate for the variable?

Comment: Yes, there are identical standard errors in those two models, but they are for the difference (and so appear to be for `var1` and `var2`). My question could be rephrased as how could you calculate the standard error of the estimate for `var1` using model2?

Comment: I don't follow what you mean by "for the difference," because explicitly the output states these are the standard errors for the estimates.

Comment: As far as I understand, the coefficent on `var1` in `model2` is for the difference between `var2` (the omitted variable) and `var1` - and thus the standard error estimate will be of that difference. That's why the standard error estimates are the same in both models, even though they are of different variable estimates.

Comment: I think I see.  Perhaps you just want to switch to a coding in which there is no intercept: use two indicators for the two values of the variable.